# Read config.xml file using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, config, readfile

I have a number of html files and a single config.xml file..Though they are seperate pages they all belong to a single project..Now my config.xml file has thig tag

```
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "com.phonegap.capexrevex"
    version   = "1.0.0">
```

Then as i already mentioned above i have a number of html pages..

In that i have my homepage "main.html".In my homepage i  need to read the version tag from my config.xml file

**How do i do this using javascript/jquery ???**

Answer (score 3):

Use the jQuery `$.get` function and you should be able to accomplish what you are trying to do.

```
$.get("config.xml", function(data){
    alert($(data).find('widget').attr('version'));
});
```

Comment: Note: the config.xml on the latest version of PhoneGap is not located inside the www folder. I know you can have one in the www folder but if you were to install a fresh copy of PhoneGap and create a new app, the directory structure does not put the config.xml in the www folder any more...